# How to cut a hole in a subdivided mesh?

Tags: modeling

Without actually applying the subdivision modifier, how can we cut a hole through the subdivided mesh? I tried using loop cuts but the topology turned out bad:
[image: bed]

Using the boolean modifier it had some artifacts and you also need to apply the modifier:
[image]

Further trying to fix them with loop cuts gave this strange edges:
[image]

and scaling them along the y axis to zero did no good. So **How can we cut a hole through a subdivisioned mesh without actually applying the modifiers?** I know disabling the boolean modifier would give a nice hole in the render but what if we have to do some editing with the part, like adding a drawer object(particularly in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Inset tool. That way you can keep the topology as quads.

Select the faces where you need the cut, press <kbd>I</kbd> to activate the inset tool, and then by dragging the mouse you can determine the size of the hole.

After just extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) and delete the faces as needed.

[image]

Comment: ho do you make such a replay ?